# Ruby: How do you search for a substring, and increment a value within it?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to change a file by finding this string:

```
<aspect name=\"lineNumber\"><![CDATA[{CLONEINCR}]]>
```

and replacing `{CLONEINCR}` with an incrementing number.  Here's what I have so far:

```rb
file = File.open('input3400.txt' , 'rb')
contents = file.read.lines.to_a
contents.each_index do |i|contents.join["<aspect name=\"lineNumber\"><![CDATA[{CLONEINCR}]]></aspect>"] = "<aspect name=\"lineNumber\"><![CDATA[#{i}]]></aspect>" end
file.close
```

But this seems to go on forever - do I have an infinite loop somewhere?

Note: my text file is 533,952 lines long.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do, but the loop will finish after 533,952 iterations.

Comment: I'm trying to search for the string `<aspect name=\"lineNumber\"><![CDATA[{CLONEINCR}]]></aspect>` and replace `{CLONEINCR}` with an incrementing number.

Comment: @ctote Are you trying to alter the file? Or store the result in a variable? The code you posted won't do either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeatedly concatenating all the elements of `contents`, making a substitution, and throwing away the result. This is happening once for each line, so no wonder it is taking a long time.

The easiest solution would be to read the entire file into a single string and use `gsub` on that to modify the contents. In your example you are inserting the (zero-based) file line numbers into the CDATA. I suspect this is a mistake.

This code replaces all occurrences of `<![CDATA[{CLONEINCR}]]>` with `<![CDATA[1]]>`, `<![CDATA[2]]>` etc. with the number incrementing for each matching CDATA found. The modified file is sent to STDOUT. Hopefully that is what you need.

```
File.open('input3400.txt' , 'r') do |f|
  i = 0
  contents = f.read.gsub('<![CDATA[{CLONEINCR}]]>') { |m|
    m.sub('{CLONEINCR}', (i += 1).to_s)
  }
  puts contents
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it works. I am wondering why mine doesn't (other than the fact I wasn't saving my data anywhere)?

Comment: @ctote: Well, precisely that. Isn't it enough? You were creating a string, modifying it, and throwing it away, over and over again. That doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @ctote If this answer was the most helpful to you, please consider giving it the checkmark.  That will help others who find your question to quickly see which answer you considered best.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to replace CLONEINCR with the line number, which is what your above code looks like it's trying to do, then this will work. Otherwise see Borodin's answer.

```
output = File.readlines('input3400.txt').map.with_index do |line, i|
  line.gsub "<aspect name=\"lineNumber\"><![CDATA[{CLONEINCR}]]></aspect>",
    "<aspect name=\"lineNumber\"><![CDATA[#{i}]]></aspect>"
end
File.write('input3400.txt', output.join(''))
```

Also, you should be aware that when you read the lines into `contents`, you are creating a `String` distinct from the file. You can't operate on the file directly. Instead you have to create a new `String` that contains what you want and then overwrite the original file.

Comment: A little explanation would be nice.